# How to use dcast() to stack/collapse string column by group

Tags: r, data.table

```
DT <- data.table(id = rep(1:3, 2),
                    class = rep(letters[1:6]),
                    des = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 3))
```

which looks like this:

```
   id class des
1:  1     a   A
2:  2     b   B
3:  3     c   A
4:  1     d   B
5:  2     e   A
6:  3     f   B
```

The question is that I need to stack different value (string type) of variables class & des in each id into one row, that is, **how to convert that data.table into the following shape**:

```
   id    class      des
1:  1     a, d     A, B
2:  2     b, e     B, A
3:  3     c, f     A, B
```

I have tried something like this, but the result is not what I expected.

```
DT %>% 
  dcast(id ~ ..., fun = function(x) paste(x, ", "), value.var = c("class", "des"))

   id   class    des
1:  1    d ,    B , 
2:  2    e ,    A , 
3:  3    f ,    B ,
```

Comment: depending on what you want to do afterwards you can also try this `library(tidyverse);
DT %>% 
  tidyr::nest(-id)` and use `purrr:map` functionality afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use `dcast()`. It is much simpler to group your `data.table` by `id` and then go through the columns using `lapply()` and use `paste()` with `collapse = ", "` to summarise:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ", "), by = id]
```

The result looks like this:

```
   id class  des
1:  1  a, d A, B
2:  2  b, e B, A
3:  3  c, f A, B
```

You will find that this solution is much faster than using `dcast()`:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(dcast = dcast(DT, id ~ ..., 
                            fun = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "), 
                            value.var = c("class", "des")),
               group = DT[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ", "), by = id],
               times = 100)

Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 dcast 2460.732 2639.4095 3118.5706 2815.3385 3221.251 6942.144   100
 group  305.014  329.2315  374.9927  347.6135  377.440  670.746   100
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Caleb, that is the answer of ozacha. But as you can see, clemens' solution is much faster.

Comment: @hpesoj626, yes. Thank you all.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you will accept a `dplyr` solution, the following can be a solution.

```
DT %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(class, des), paste, collapse = ", ")
```

Comment: Thanks! If my dataset is not that large, I would do it this way.

Comment: This is actually faster than the `dcast` solution. But @clemens solution is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

**Collapse** is the important part – use `paste(x, collapse = ", ")` to perfrom the string aggregation:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

DT %>% 
   dcast(id ~ ..., 
         fun = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "), 
         value.var = c("class", "des"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I just notice the argument of [collapse] is different from the default one. [:embarrassed]